# How to enable up arrow in Rakudo REPL on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: command-line, 21.10, readline, rakudo

I'm installed Rakudo on Ubuntu 21.10 by running this command:

```
sudo apt install rakudo
```

Now I can run the Raku REPL by running `raku` or `rakudo`.

I would like to be able to select the previous command by typing the up arrow, just like you can in the Python on Node REPL, for instance. Instead, this is what happens when I press the arrow key:

```
$ raku
> say "hello";
hello
> ^[[A
```

How do I make the up arrow work?

Comment: For Ubuntu 22.04, see this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1422671/2355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is contained in the output of Rakudo when you run it:

```
$ rakudo
Welcome to ™ v2020.12.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2020.12.

You may want to `zef install Readline` or `zef install Linenoise` or use rlwrap for a line editor

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
>
```

That is, we need to run `zef install Readline`. From the command-line, make sure that `zef` is installed by running:

```
sudo apt install perl6-zef
```

Then install the Raku module named `Readline` by running:

```
zef install Readline
```

If you get test failures, you may need to run this:

```
zef install Readline --force-test
```

Now when you run `raku` or `rakudo`, you will get the expected behaviour when pressing up arrow, which the library Readline enables.