# What is the best way to install Raku on Ubuntu 22.04 with readline or a line editor?

Tags: 22.04, readline, rakudo

On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I can install Rakudo (formerly known as Perl 6) like this:

```
sudo apt install rakudo
```

Then when I run `raku` on the command-line, I get this output:

```
$ raku
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.02.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.02.

You may want to `zef install Readline`, `zef install Linenoise`, or `zef install Terminal::LineEditor` or use rlwrap for a line editor

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
>
```

I do want to have line editing features for the Raku REPL. What is the best option here for Ubuntu? Should I install a package with `zef` or with `sudo apt`? Where do the packages get installed and how do I undo that?

If I try to run `zef`, I get a command not found error. If I run `sudo apt install perl6-zef`, I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package perl6-zef
```

Comment: It seems this package got caught in an unfortunate gap - `perl6-zef` was replaced by `raku-zef` in Debian, but the import from Debian for Ubuntu 22.04 took place at a time when the former was gone and the latter not added yet.

Comment: I forgot that I asked a similar question for Ubuntu 21.10: https://askubuntu.com/q/1402248/2355 However, the solution doesn't work for Ubuntu 22.04, since the `perl6-zef` package doesn't exist in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

I think the best answer right now, unfortunately, is to install rakudo from https://rakudo.org/downloads, then install zef from https://github.com/ugexe/zef, and then use zef to install Readline.

Answer (score 1):

https://rakudo.org/downloads
had the most current binary images.
Download, untar and fix your PATH.

Comment: Hi Fritz! That's great that Rakudo provides binary exectuables that can be downloaded. However, when I run `raku`, I notice that it doesn't have readline support, I still get the message "You may want to `zef install Readline`". However, the download does not include `zef`.